# how to add questions with grades

Tags: functions, scripting

I want to add questions with grades,
I'm using this form to write questions :

```
QuestionObject["How many career home runs did Hank Aaron hit?", 
 AssessmentFunction[{714 -> False, 755 -> True, 868 -> False}]]
```

but I did not find any way to add grades.
*If possible to add multiple questions with grades and one button to submit then the grade appears...

thanks in advance!

Comment: `asmf=AssessmentFunction[ {755 -> <|
   "Score" -> 10, "Correct" -> True, 
   "Explanation" -> 
    "755 is the answer"|>
    ,  714 -> <|
   "Score" -> 3, "Correct" -> False, 
   "Explanation" -> 
    "Too low"|>
    ,868 -> <|
   "Score" -> 1, "Correct" -> False, 
   "Explanation" -> 
    "Too high"|>}]` and `QuestionObject["How many career home runs did Hank Aaron hit?", 
asmf]`. Also try: `Normal@asmf[755]` e.g. to assess an answer. Incorporation of scores in a larger context is something I cannot help you with.